# errors in google adsense

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I am getting the below errors after analyzing my site with Firebug:

```
TypeError: a is null
[Break On This Error]   

...right,",pt:",f.top,",pb:",f.bottom,",vl:",b.left,",vr:",b.right,",vt:",b.top,",v...

osd.js (line 25)



TypeError: a is null
[Break On This Error]   

...getComputedStyle&&(c=c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a,k))?c[b]||c.getPropertyVal...

show_ads_impl.js (line 42)
```

Anyone can help how can I fix them.

I am not a developer, I just have simple site with google adsence.

When I try to open site with compatability view off in IE9 it freezes showing that I have long scrip runing on my page, when I on compatability view it works fine.  Will all visitors of my site have a problem viewing my site?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you place the code?

Comment: I placed it in right column as below:

<div class="rightcolmiddleblock">
   
 
<div id="googlerightcol">
 
here I placed google ad code  
     
</div>
   
      

</div>

Comment: Javascript code in `<div>`?

Comment: it is not exactly javascript code, if you familiar with google add, you just copy html code

Comment: then this code contains a link to javascript file

Comment: Include this code in your post.